# Requisições concorrentes usando axios sem perder a sessão

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request, web-crawler

Estou desenvolvendo um crawler usando axios. Como posso fazer múltiplas requisições ou callbacks sem perder a sessão e sem ter que manipular cookies? Observe o exemplo abaixo. Ao fazer login recebo como no header da resposta uma set-cookie, porém espero que o próprio axios configure ele.

```
function login() {
  return axios.post('/login');
}

function getUser() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/');
}

axios.all([login(), getUser()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {

  }));
```

Já tentei com withCredentials mas sem resultados

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um módulo que suporte `cookies` no seu `axios`, como por exemplo o [`axios-cookiejar-support`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support).

> [`axios-cookiejar-support`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-cookiejar-support)
>
> ```
> const axios = require('axios').default;
> const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('@3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support').default;
> // const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;
> const tough = require('tough-cookie');
>
> axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);
>
> const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();
>
> axios.get('https://google.com', {
>   jar: cookieJar, // tough.CookieJar or boolean
>   withCredentials: true // If true, send cookie stored in jar
> })
> .then(() => {
>   console.log(cookieJar);
> });
> ```